# How to find doubles with SQL?

Tags: sql

Using the [Chinook Test Database](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) I wrote this SQL statement to show all the tracks ordered by two specific customers:

```
SELECT inv.BillingCity,cus.LastName,tra.Name
        FROM invoice AS inv
        JOIN customer AS cus ON inv.CustomerId=cus.CustomerId
        JOIN invoiceline inl ON inv.InvoiceId=inl.InvoiceId
        JOIN track tra ON tra.TrackId=inl.TrackId
        WHERE cus.LastName IN ('Schneider','Schröder')
        ORDER BY inv.BillingCity,cus.LastName,tra.Name
```

I see that there is a track that was ordered twice by one customer:

[image]

**How would I write an SQL statement to find doubles like this, i.e. "return all tracks ordered multiple times by one customer"?**

Comment: select BillingCity, lastName, Name
from invoice
groupe by BillingCity, lastName, Name
having count(*) >1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT cus.CustomerId,tra.Name,COUNT(cus.CustomerId) AS tot
       FROM invoice AS inv
       JOIN customer AS cus ON inv.CustomerId=cus.CustomerId
       JOIN invoiceline inl ON inv.InvoiceId=inl.InvoiceId
       JOIN track tra ON tra.TrackId=inl.TrackId
       GROUP BY cus.CustomerId,tra.Name
       HAVING tot > 1
```

Comment: select BillingCity, lastName, Name
from invoice
groupe by BillingCity, lastName, Name
having count(*) >1